# How to SaveAs, renaming file with increasing value, without a prompt due to file previously existing?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, do-while

I wrote a Do While loop to increment my filename by 1 if it detects a file with the same name in my file path.

For example, if a filename #5 in my path, it will save the file as #6. And so on.

```vb
Sub Increment_My_File()
    
    Dim myfile As String, mypath As String, mycount As Integer, _
      mydate As String
    
    mycount = 1
    
    mydate = Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YYYY")
    
    mypath = "C:\Users\reggie\OneDrive\Documents\"
                 
    myfile = "Account Breakdown " & mydate & " #" & mycount _ 
      & " Inventory Allocation"
          
    Workbooks.Add            
    'and do some code
    
    Do While Dir(myfile) <> ""
    
        myfile = "Account Breakdown " & mydate & " #" & mycount _ 
          & " Inventory Allocation"
           
        mycount = mycount + 1
          
        'myfile = Dir   '<<<don't know its purpose; does not help it seems
            
    Loop    
    
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=C:\Users\reggie\OneDrive\Documents\" & _
       myfile

End Sub
```

The code prompts me to overwrite the existing filename.

For example with a #1 instead of automatically increasing `mycount` integer by 1 to #2 within the path.

I've tried every which way to change my dir to `dir(mypath & myfile)` etc.

Comment: You check in myFile for File, but you save in myPath & myFile. If you ommit a folder and just use a filename, the file is stored in default path, usually`%UserProfile%\Documents\`so you look at the wrong place for already saved Workbooks what causes overwrite prompt. You can avoid this with [debugging](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) .

Comment: Hello ComputerVersteher, thanks for your comment. I'm not sure what you mean and how I can improve my code. It still gives me a prompt to overwrite it. I want my files saved in my path and just increment by 1 from the last iteration (for example #8 goes to #9), Any thoughts?

Comment: You check the `myFile`path for a file existing, but myFile just contains sth like`Account Breakdown 06-16-2019 #1 Inventory Allocation`what is just a filename without folders. As you need a folder (at least a drive) to find a file office adds the [Default local file location](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/set-a-default-working-folder-786200a7-f5f2-4d26-a3ae-b78c60dd5d3b), what is usually`%UserProfile%\Documents`. Now you save the workbook at`C:\Users\reggie\**OneDrive\**Documents\Account Breakdown 06-16-2019 #1 Inventory Allocation` where you didn't search for file exists.

Comment: If you use debugging like I suggested , you see that the while loop is never run beause`Dir(myFile)`is empty from the beginning. Instead use`Dir(myPath & myFile)`to search in correct pfolder!

Comment: yep, tried Dir(myPath & myFile) but still doesn't work :(

Comment: Because the file extension is missing (`.xlsx`)! Look at @Nathan's answer! And please start [debugging](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) to avoid these nasty errors.

Comment: Thank you ComputerVersteher for your comments, especially about debugging and .xlsx...the code runs nicely!

Comment: Please mark @Nathan's answer as accepted and vote for it! And I forgot to mention [Rubberduck-VBA](http://rubberduckvba.com/) a nice open source vba addin with e.g. Code Inspections, that can show you many ways to improve your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increment mycount 
**before** you reconstruct
myfile.

[image: Line Swap]

As mentioned by @ComputerVersteher, you also need to utilize the path.

```
Sub Increment_My_File()

      Dim myfile As String, mypath As String, mycount As Integer, _
              mydate As String, wb as Workbook

      mydate = Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YYYY")
      mypath = "C:\Users\reggie\OneDrive\Documents\"

      Set wb = Workbooks.Add
      'and do some code

      Do
          mycount = mycount + 1
          myfile = mypath & "Account Breakdown " & mydate & " #" & mycount _
              & " Inventory Allocation.xlsx"
          'Dir   '<<<this would return the next file name in the folder. Not what you are trying to do
      Loop Until Dir(myfile) = ""

      wb.SaveAs Filename:=myfile

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nathan!

I've put mycount before myfile, and set myfile on top (outside the loop) to:  myfile = Dir(mypath & ".xlsx").... now the only thing is that myfile saves at 1+1 = #2, VBA does not detect #2 to increase it by 1 to get #3 and so on

Comment: No, only change the order, not outside loop myfile.

Comment: @NathanSutherland:Compare`Dir(myfile)` and `SaveAs Filename:=C:\Users\reggie\OneDrive\Documents\" & myfile`! See the diff?  ;)

Comment: Hi Nathan, I rearranged the order and reverted back myfile but the error still occurs, that I am prompted to overwrite it.. I don't see what 's wrong with the logic. Increment mycount by 1 if condition Dir(myfile) is met

Comment: Sorry about the slipshod reply, I have edited with a more thorough answer.

Comment: Thank you Nathan very much for your edit, my code now runs perfectly! The answer is correct

Comment: As OP has understood you can remove (or reduce to a link) the image on top. One suggestion: save the returned Workbook regerence of`Workbooks.Add`and use it instead of`ActiveWorkbook`at Saveas. I would use a`With`statement for that to avoid declaring a var.